# Library / code for trapdoor hashes?

Tags: hash, cryptography, jce

has anyone experience with trapdoor hashes? I was looking for some code example or a Java library which I could use. Or is there a way to create those hashes with the given tools, e.g. JCE?

Kind regards
Oliver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common trapdoor hash functions are [RSA](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/RSA) and [Rabin](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Rabin_cryptosystem) who both rely on the difficulty of factorization. Here are some Java projects which implement these:

- [RSA encryption in Java](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/rsa_encryption.shtml)
- [RSA.java](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/78crypto/RSA.java.html)
- [Java RSA Encryption: An example](http://andreas.louca.org/2008/03/20/java-rsa-encryption-an-example/)
- [Rabin Hash Function](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rabinhash/)
- [rabinfingerprint](https://code.google.com/p/rabinfingerprint/)

Comment: Hi Sjoerd and thanks for the answer. Does this mean you do the hashing using asymmetric cryptography? E.g. I sign some string with a public key and that's the trapdoor?

Comment: @OliverSchmidt You would encrypt with the public key, not sign. (And I wouldn't count this as a hash, as it is not completely deterministic). Yes, a trapdoor one-way function is a primitive from which one can build an asymmetric cryptosystem.

Comment: Thanks Paŭlo! But how does the hash look like? If I encrypted something, I get some ciphertext. But if I encrypted it another time, I would get another ciphertext which wouldn't compare to the first one.